# Google vision API changes app pictures with its own pictures

Tags: android, google-vision

I am making an app using Google Vision API for face detection. As the pictures show, my app displays two images normally without Google Vision, but with it Google Vision automatically changes the two images with its own.

The images are stored inside the drawable folder, stored in an SQLite database through their id (for example, R.drawable.crown_flowers) and fetched at runtime from the database.

The code that performs the face detection itself is not responsible for the behavior. Simply having

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0'
```

in the build.gradle file causes this behavior, even if the library is not referenced anywhere in the actual code. I have tried using a more recent version of the library (11.8.0) but to no avail.

[image: Without Google Vision]

[image: With Google Vision]

**Edit:** doing some debugging I found that the problem is with the SQLite database. If I reference the pictures only by their drawable id without fetching them from the database, the app works correctly. The problem is that this app is for a school project and I am required to use SQLite. This is code for the database:

From the DatabaseConnector class:

```
public class DatabaseConnector extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DatabaseConnector(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public void queryData(String sqlString) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL(sqlString);
    }

    public void insertData(String name, int imgUrl) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        String sqlString = "INSERT INTO FILTER VALUES (NULL, ?, ?);";

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sqlString);
        statement.bindString(1, name);
        statement.bindLong(2, imgUrl);
        statement.execute();
    }

    public Cursor getData(String sqlString) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

        return database.rawQuery(sqlString, null);
    }
}
```

This is where data is inserted in the database inside the Activity class:

```
private void connectDatabase() {
    databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this, "FilterDB.sqlite", null, 1);

    databaseConnector.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILTER (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, image INTEGER);");


    if (databaseConnector.getData("SELECT * FROM FILTER").getCount() < 2) {
        databaseConnector.insertData("Primavera", R.drawable.crown_flowers);
        databaseConnector.insertData("Desir", R.drawable.sparkle);
    }
}
```

And this is where the images are fetched from the database:

```
Cursor cursor = ((HomepageActivity)mActivity).databaseConnector.getData("SELECT * FROM FILTER");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst() && position > 16) {
        mFilters.clear();
        do {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            int imgId = (int)cursor.getLong(2);

            mFilters.add(new OverFilter(id, name, imgId));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Just for clarity, this is the OverFilter class:

```
public class OverFilter {

    private String mName;
    private int mImage;
    private int mId;

    public OverFilter(int mId, String mName, int mImage) {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mImage = mImage;
        this.mId = mId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    public void setImage(int mImage) {
        this.mImage = mImage;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(int mId) {
        this.mId = mId;
    }
}
```

mFilter is just an ArrayList of OverFilter.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: What's the name of your drawables that you use for those images in your project? Google Vision might have drawables with the same name, and then yours might get overridden.

Comment: @Moonbloom good point, but that does not seem to be the problem. If I display the pictures by simply creating a Bitmap object from their drawable id (without using the database) they are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might run into the same problem in the future, I solved it by changing the pictures's primary key id in the database. I made it non autoincremented and I set it manually to a number that seemed unlikely to me to have any conflicts with the pictures stored in the Google vision library.
This is the updated code:

```
public void insertData(int id, String name, int imgUrl) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sqlString = "INSERT INTO FILTER VALUES (?, ?, ?);";

    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sqlString);
    statement.bindLong(1, id);
    statement.bindString(2, name);
    statement.bindLong(3, imgUrl);
    statement.execute();
}

private void connectDatabase() {
    databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this, "FilterDB.sqlite", null, 1);

    databaseConnector.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILTER (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR, image INTEGER);");


    if (databaseConnector.getData("SELECT * FROM FILTER").getCount() < 2) {
        databaseConnector.insertData(578,"Primavera", R.drawable.crown_flowers);
        databaseConnector.insertData(579,"Desir", R.drawable.sparkle);
    }
}
```